# Fill a block element with left most floating child (float: right)

Tags: html, css, fill-parent

I need to fill a `<LI>` width element with his most left child (out of three childs). Those three childs are formated with `display: inline-block; float: right`.

what i achieved so far:

[image]

what i expected to achieve:

[image]

It's obviously that `width: 66%` don't help anyway. Also a 100% width will not work.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527824/dithering-child-elements-dimensions-to-fill-a-parent-element) on stackoverflow, but I need something made in pure CSS, no JS, jQuery, etc. Also, using a table is not a solution for me.

If the HTML code can help in this matter:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    ul {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    li {
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;

        border-color: #D5AB55 #C93 #C93 #D5AB55;
        background-color: #F3CE00;
    }

    .name {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        height: 18px;
        width: 65%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px 2px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .save, .cancel {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .save   { background: url(../images/confirm.png) no-repeat center center; }
    .cancel { background: url(../images/cancel.png) no-repeat center center; }
</style>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
            <input type="button" value="" class="save">
            <input type="text" value="Big list item" class="name">
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li id="category_2" id_category="2">
                <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                <input type="text" value="Medium list item" class="name">
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                    <input type="text" value="1st small item" class="name">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                    <input type="text" value="2nd small item" class="name">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                    <input type="text" value="3rd small item" class="name">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time,

SYNCRo,

Comment: You realise your HTML is invalid, right? The *only* valid child of `ul` (or `ol`) is an `li` element: nesting a `ul` directly within another `ul` is not valid HTML (they'd need to be contained within a parent `li` tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having corrected your invalid HTML (as noted in the comment to your question *no* element other than an `li` is a valid child of a `ul` or `ol`, *including* those elements themselves) to the following:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="items">
            <input type="button" value="" class="cancel" />
            <input type="button" value="" class="save" />
            <input type="text" value="Big list item" class="name" />
        </li>
        <li>
        <ul>
            <li id="category_2" id_category="2" class="items">
                <input type="button" value="" class="cancel" />
                <input type="button" value="" class="save" />
                <input type="text" value="Medium list item" class="name" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <ul>
                <li class="items">
                    <input type="button" value="" class="cancel" />
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save" />
                    <input type="text" value="1st small item" class="name" />
                </li>
                <li class="items">
                    <input type="button" value="" class="cancel" />
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save" />
                    <input type="text" value="2nd small item" class="name" />
                </li>
                <li class="items">
                    <input type="button" value="" class="cancel" />
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save" />
                    <input type="text" value="3rd small item" class="name" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I had to add a class to those `li` elements that contain children (since the previous, simple, `li` selector now matches the multiple elements in the hierarchy), in this case the class `items`, but adjust to taste.

The following CSS works, albeit only with a pretty up-to-date browser:

```
li {
    width: 80%;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}

li.items {
    background-color: #f90;
}

li .save, li .cancel {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

input.name {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 45px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 45px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 45px);
    width: -ms-calc(100% - 45px);
    width: calc(100% - 45px);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bzF93/).

This uses the CSS `calc()` function to determine the width of the `input` element as a calculation.

To be cross-browser compatible with the older browsers you could use, instead, absolute (for the `.save` and `.cancel` elements) and relative (for the `li` elements) positioning:

```
li {
    width: 80%;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
    position: relative;
}

li.items {
    background-color: #f90;
    padding: 0 45px 0 0;
}

li .save, li .cancel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.save {
    top: 0;
    right: 21px;
}

.cancel {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

input.name {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bzF93/2/).

You'll note that the `padding` gets added to the width of the `li` elements, of course, so you may wish to add the `box-sizing` CSS property to compensate for that:

```
/* all other CSS remains untouched */
li {
    width: 80%;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bzF93/3/).

References:

- [CSS `box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing).
- [CSS `calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc).

Comment: amazing answer, thanks a lot. Give me some time to digerate it and i'll set your answer as the accepted one. Thanks again. And yes, it looks like an invalid <ul><li> tree will affect my final layout. Never tought so, lol

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, hopefully it's of help to you! =)

Answer (score 0):

try this: just add another class with other width

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
        <input type="button" value="" class="save">
        <input type="text" value="Big list item" class="name_big_list">
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li id="category_2" id_category="2">
            <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
            <input type="button" value="" class="save">
            <input type="text" value="Medium list item" class="name_medium_list ">
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                <input type="text" value="1st small item" class="name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                <input type="text" value="2nd small item" class="name">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="button" value="" class="cancel">
                <input type="button" value="" class="save">
                <input type="text" value="3rd small item" class="name">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

​

CSS:

```
 div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
}
li {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    border-color: #D5AB55 #C93 #C93 #D5AB55;
    background-color: #F3CE00;
}

.name, .name_big_list, .name_medium_list {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 18px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.name_big_list{
width: 73%
}
.name_medium_list{
width: 69%;
}
.save, .cancel {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.save   { background: url(../images/confirm.png) no-repeat center center; }
.cancel { background: url(../images/cancel.png) no-repeat center center; }​
```

Comment: I'm sorry but if i change div's width to 300px i'll have to recalculate all percentages. And in my example i have just three types of list items. In reality i'll never know the real depth of the list.