# When do browsers round pixel fractions to full pixels and when do they not?

Tags: css, pixel, subpixel

I remember having read here on SO that pixel fractions should be generally avoided in CSS because browsers tend to round them to full pixels.

And indeed, the below example shows how `0.3` pixels are rounded to a full pixel:

```css
span {
  border: 0.3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
```

I am very surprised because I seem to have found a counterexample:

```css
span {
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.3px black;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
```

Compare with `1px`:

```css
span {
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
```

I'm not complaining *that* it happens, on the contrary it's almost a lifesaver for me, but I'd like to understand *why* does it happen.

- When are browsers rounding pixel fractions to full pixels? And when are they not? What are the rules here?
- Can I rely on browsers not rounding `0.3px` to `1px` in the above example? Is this behavior consistent across browsers? Or is relying on this behavior a recipe for trouble?
- HOW does this happen at all? On laptops a pixel should be indivisible bc of hardware (monitor) limitations?

Comment: [Relevant spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#actual) for anyone digging deeper into this. At a glance the spec says it's up to the implementation, but perhaps someone can shine more light on it.

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587820/391715) on another question about CSS subpixels

Answer (score 1):

Well per the Spec rounding is up to the implementor (browser render engine). However, that only appears to apply to layout rules like borders. I think that's intentional since text rendering seems to utilize OS level render systems that include anti-aliasing techniques for HiDPI displays and LCDs.

#### Rendering Fonts

My guess is that your "working" example only works because it's text. In Webkit based browsers you can tweak the rendering result using CSS `text-rendering`. Here's [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering)

#### Rendering HTML Elements

However, if you want sub-pixel rendering or better smoothing you can apply a CSS `transform: translateZ(0)` to elements. At least in Chrome and I believe other modern browsers, this will force subpixel aliasing. But I don't know that it will override the browsers rounding that likely happens before the rendering.